# Watson DSX got "Index Error" but Docker Jupiter env. don't

Tags: python, data-science-experience

I run following Python script on Watson DSX and got error.
(IndexError: list index out of range)

(1) Same program run normally on Docker Jupiter notebook env.

(2) On Waston DSX run normally if input file size change small.

Would you please tell my what is the reason for it, and what should I do not to occur error?

```
!pip install janome
data = get_object_storage_file_with_credentials_8b9fb794cc1049b09563d144c8861966('KITDemo', 'kusa-out.txt')
#data = get_object_storage_file_with_credentials_8b9fb794cc1049b09563d144c8861966('KITDemo', 'kusa2-out.txt')
txt = data.getvalue()

word_list = []
from janome.tokenizer import Tokenizer
t = Tokenizer()
for token in t.tokenize(txt, stream=True):
    partOfSpeech = token.part_of_speech.split(',')[0]
    if partOfSpeech == u'名詞':
        word_list.append(token.surface)
```

---

Here is the full stack trace.

```
IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9a7681ae1aa6> in <module>()
      2 from janome.tokenizer import Tokenizer
      3 t = Tokenizer()
----> 4 for token in t.tokenize(txt, stream=True):
      5     partOfSpeech = token.part_of_speech.split(',')[0]
      6     if partOfSpeech == u'名詞':
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lob7h.png)

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Could be a problem in the input data, which leads the tokenizer to generate empty tokens, or to trigger the IndexError itself. Have you tried with different large input data sets, or just with one? Maybe add some debug output, for example by printing `token` at the beginning of the loop. Then inspect the input data after the last token that gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexError: list index out of range` was fixed at Janome version 0.3.6.
https://github.com/mocobeta/janome/blob/0.3.6/CHANGES.txt

Please upgrade janome. If you still have problems after upgrading, please create an issue here. 
https://github.com/mocobeta/janome/issues